# <Select /> component from react-select looks strange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to use `<Select />` component from react-select, so I've copied an example from the component's site https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

```
    import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'    
    import Select from 'react-select'
    import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'

    export default class Test extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

      }

    render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Select
              name="form-field-name"
              value='hello'
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={[
                { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
                { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
              ]}
            />
          </Fragment>
        )
      }
    }
```

But it looks strange:
[image]

What should I do in order to make it looks like this?

[image]

Comment: Well, we can't see your CSS or anything else, so it'll be tough to help.

Comment: I'm just using component's CSS 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'  @Dave Newton

Answer (score 2):

The import of `import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'` is the issue here. To include 'react-select' in your app,  you just need to use`import Select from 'react-select'` and it will do all the job. You will get the exact type-ahead drop-down box as shown in the original example.

Just to wrap it perfectly in the app, you can use the traditional `div` with the `className` and you will get what you're looking for.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the same result

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the component's CSS isn't loading properly or its styles are being overridden.